# Google Sheets: Help excluding data from SUMIFS

Tags: google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I am using the following formula to sum the total number of hours in the 'Time Sheets' sheet between 2 dates:

```
=SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2022",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2023")
```

[image]

This is working but I would also like to be able to add a filter so that I can exclude anything from column A with certain codes (eg PP999, PP998 etc.) within the same date range.

[image]

I have been using the formula below as a work round however the formula is becoming rather long and it is limiting how I can use it, can anyone help with this?

```
=SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2022",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2023")-SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!A2:A,"PP999",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2022",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2023")-SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!A2:A,"PP998",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2022",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2023")-SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!A2:A,"PP997",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2022",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2023")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach you can try out:

```
=sum(ifna(filter('Time Sheet'!K2:K,'Time Sheet'!G2:G>=date(2022,12,1),'Time Sheet'!G2:G<=date(2023,30,11),iserror(xmatch('Time Sheet'!A2:A,{"PP997","PP998","PP999"})))))
```

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow, the formula you provided is working for the original date range however when I have tried to edit it to do the same for the previous year (changing the dates to (2021,12,1) and (2022,11,30)) it is returning a total greater than the sum of all the unfiltered data for that time period, do you know where I may be going wrong?

Comment: sorry hard to troubleshoot just based on the description itself.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to all this so I appreciate your help. I'm trying to do the same thing in another cell but for a different date range (01/12/21 - 01/11/30). I changed the formula to: =sum(ifna(filter('Time Sheet'!K2:K,'Time Sheet'!G2:G>=date(2021,12,1),'Time Sheet'!G2:G<=date(2022,30,11),iserror(xmatch('Time Sheet'!A2:A,{"PP997","PP998","PP999"})))))  the result returned with this formula is greater than when using the formula: =SUMIFS('Time Sheet'!$K$2:$K,'Time Sheet'!G2:G,">=01/12/2021",'Time Sheet'!G2:G,"<=30/11/2022")

Comment: care to share a sample sheet with realistic demo data maybe and desired output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture on how to best amend the current formula...

Comment: I have realised the different total to what I was expecting was due to the different date formats we use in the UK. Your original answer gives the result I was expecting when the dates are formatted the same across both sheets. Many thanks